# Right Side and Left Side Of Bessel's Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

what's is the difference between the left side and the right side of Bessel's Inequality? Isn't both would evaluate to sum of coefficient squared of an element $x$ of a Hilbert space?

Thank you!

Comment: The sum doesn't necessarily include every basis vector making up $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Bessel's inequality is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2 \leq \|x\|^2_2,$$

where $e_i$ is *any* orthonormal sequence. When $e_i$ is complete (i.e. a basis of $H$) then we do obtain an exact equality.

Comment: Noted: When $e_i$ is complete (i.e. a basis of $H$) then we do obtain an exact equality.

Don't know if I'm still on track. To have a better grasp at the working of Bessel's Inequality, I try to work out an example. Consider the following orthonormal for $\mathbb{R^3}$:$u_1 = (\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}}), u_2 = (0,  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}), u_3 = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},  \frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ 

and where $x = (1, 2, 3) \in H$

Comment: $$|\langle x,u_1\rangle|^2 = |1.\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} +  2.\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} + 3.\frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}}|^2 = |0|^2$$

$$ |\langle x,u_2\rangle|^2 = |1.0 +  2.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + 3.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|^2 = |\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}|^2$$

$$ |\langle x,u_3\rangle|^2 = |1.\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + 2.\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} + 3.\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|^2 = |\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}|^2$$

Comment: Then, $$\sum_{k=1}^3 |\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2 = |0|^2 + |\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}|^2 + |\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}|^2 = \frac{89}{18}$$

While, $$\|x\|^2 = \langle x,x \rangle = (1.1)+(2.2)+(3.3) = 14 $$

Hence, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2 = \frac {89}{1} \leq \|x\|^2_2 = 14$$

Comment: You have two mistakes. $(x,u_1)$ is incorrect, it's not 0.  $(x,u_2)$ inner product is incorrect: the first term should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{ e_k \}$ is an orthonormal subset of a Hilbert space $H$, then $Px=\sum_{k}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto the closed linear subspace spanned by the elements of $\{ e_k \}$. Then
$$
               x = \left[x-\sum_k \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k\right]+\sum_k \langle x,e_k \rangle e_k
$$
is an orthogonal decomposition, which leads to
$$
            \|x\|^2 = \left\|x-\sum_{k}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k \right\|^2
     + \sum_k |\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2.
$$
So the difference is
$$
            \|x\|^2-\sum_k |\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2=\left\|x-\sum_{k}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k \right\|^2
$$
Bessel's inequality is equality iff $x = \sum_k \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$.